# Install PHP v 8 on windows server

Tags: php, windows

I have a windows server and I want to install Codeigniter application on windows server. For that I am looking to install PHP V 8 on it.

I know, How to install and configure it on Normal windows. But I don't know how to configure it on windows server.

Can anyone please help me with the same?

Thanks.

Comment: You can install XAMPP for PHP 8.0.
Go to apachefriends.org and download it.

Comment: But I don't think I can access internet and install normal softwares like windows in windows server

Comment: What version of Windows Server is it? Is this on a domain, virtual machine or a standalone computer at home? Is the server a domain controller or other infrastructure machine?

Comment: @kunal did you manage to install PHP8 in your windows server with IIS?